# Why is my label widget moving continuously automatically?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, bind

In the given code below my label is moving continuously when I press "a" and "s" whereas
when I press "w" and "d" then move the label widget continuously I have to repeatedly press "w" and "d" again and again, why is "a" and "s" behaving abnormally.

```
from tkinter import*
def move_up(event):
    label.place(x=label.winfo_x(), y=label.winfo_y()-10)

def move_down(event):
    label.place(x=label.winfo_x(), y=label.winfo_y()+10)

def move_left(event):
    label.place(x=label.winfo_x()-10, y=label.winfo_y())

def move_right(event):
    label.place(x=label.winfo_x()+10, y=label.winfo_y())

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

label = Label(window, width=5, height=5, bg="red")
label.place(x=250, y=250)
window.bind("<w>", move_up)
window.bind("<a>", move_left)
window.bind("<s>", move_down)
window.bind("<d>", move_right)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not reproducible

Comment: also if you want to make a game like this, I would suggest that you use a library that is built for that, such as `pygame`